# selenium not able to find Elements every time gives me exception

Tags: html, selenium

**Following is my HTML Code** :

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu14" 
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu14">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#LoginModel">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And Following is my selenium code
where I am getting Null Pointer Exception every time.

```
public void test3() throws Exception {
   // System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");
   driver.get(baseUrl);
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='dropdownMenu14'])")).click();
   //driver.findElement(By.id("dropdownMenu14")).click();

   driver.findElement(By.id("create_login")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.name("username")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.name("username")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Jahnvi");
   driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("123456");
   driver.findElement(By.id("check_login")).submit();
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Login")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@value='Login Your Account'])[2]")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("dropdownMenu14")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.id("logout_button")).click();
}
```

Comment: remove  driver.quit(); and put in the end

Comment: or if possible share the URL with us.

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried following code and it worked, I tried xpath instead of id,name etc.
Can please anyone explain why it worked with xpath but not with id.

```
@Test
public void test3() throws Exception {

    driver.get(baseUrl);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dropdownMenu14\"]")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.id("dropdownMenu14")).click();
    //driver.quit();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"header\"]/section[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]/ul/li/a")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"check_login\"]/div[1]/input")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"check_login\"]/div[1]/input")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"check_login\"]/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("Jahnvi");
    // driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"check_login\"]/div[2]/input")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"check_login\"]/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("123456");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"check_login\"]/div[4]/input")).submit();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@value='Login Your Account'])[2]")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"dropdownMenu14\"]")).click();
}
```

Comment: would need to see your html to know more. It's possible you're just getting lucky on a timing issue with your DOM.

Take a look at this article: https://www.quora.com/How-is-By-xpath-id-fbt_x_Check-better-than-By-id-fbt_x_Check-in-selenium-automation-If-both-are-the-same-then-what-is-better

Answer (score 1):

If there is multiple HTML tags with id="create_login" then selenium will return that it can not find the element. 
To debug the null reference exception we would need more information like the HTML DOM of the complete page, and what release of selenium webdriver you are using.

Comment: I am using selenium web driver version 3.12.0